# Moving from VB.net to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am making the big move from VB to C#.  Things have not been going too bad.  But I stuck on part of one of my treeview databound subs.  There is one part I cannot get to work. I am using a custom security to control access to app.  It has a treeview bound to a sitemap.  I have a custom attribute I added to the sitemap called "securitylevel".  A person can have multiple security levels so I build out a string with their security levels. Then I remove the nodes they do not have access to.  I could not use the .net roles because I had to use an existing database.  What I can't figure out is how to remove the parent and child nodes.  Here is what the VB code is.

```
    strNodesToHide As String = "100, 500, 900"

    Dim node As SiteMapNode = TryCast(e.Node.DataItem, SiteMapNode)

    If Len(node("SecurityLevel")) <> "0" Then
        If InStr(strNodesToHide, node("securityLevel")) Then
            e.Node.Parent.ChildNodes.Remove(e.Node)
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: So what aspect of that code are you unable to translate to C#?

Comment: Even the VB.NET code is already ugly, `Len` returns an integer and you compare it with `"1"`. Instead use `If node("SecurityLevel").Length <> 0` or  `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(node("SecurityLevel"))`

Comment: Guesswork, but if the "nodes to hide" are really `"100"`, `"500"` and `"900"`, it might be faster to have a `static readonly HashSet<string> strNodesToHide = new HashSet<string>(new []{"100", "500", "900"});` and then check `if (strNodesToHide.Contains(node["securityLevel"]))` -- and if those are really always numeric values, the real type (i.e. `int`) should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should be a quite straight-forward convertion:

```
string strNodesToHide = "100, 500, 900";

SiteMapNode node = e.Node.DataItem as SiteMapNode;

if (node["securityLevel"].length != 0) {
  if (strNodesToHide.indexOf(node["securityLevel"]) > -1) {
    e.Node.Parent.ChildNodes.Remove(e.Node);
  }
}
```

Something of the sorts :)

(haven't tested this. hope it works.)

Comment: Typo, you probably meant `strNodesToHide.indexOf(node["securityLevel"])`.

Comment: @Corak indeed. Changed it.